# Django application urls not working

Tags: django

In one application's urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^products/$', products, name="products"),
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
)
```

In base project urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^$', include('app.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Why http://127.0.0.1:8000/ - works fine with app.views.index method
while http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/ - returns 404 error and is not defined in url routes?

Spent some time on it already and can't find solution, maybe there is something simple that I miss...

Comment: did you import `app.views` in `app.urls` ?

Comment: tried with import and without

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your base urls should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^', include('app.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: it didn't help "products" route to work, but broke "index" route

Comment: If you remove the trailing slash, and move the pattern below the admin one, you will be able to access both the index and the products views.

Comment: Tried (r'^', include('app.urls')), - works fine for all cases

Comment: it works only with r'^' not with r'^/' as you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The '$' is only used for urls. If you look at the doc, it will tell you not use the '$' when using include().

Answer (score 4):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^', include('app.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

worked fine.

Comment: you should move the line for the admin urls BEFORE your apps.urls!

Comment: I also thought I should, for some reason admin url still works with such configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue while using path() in Django URLs.
The simple fix is you don't have to use the slash at the end of the path otherwise Django will take that URL as a complete URL and will not go to the next urls.py file

```
//this will not work    
path('/', include('app.urls'), name='profile_page')

// but this will work
path('', include('app.urls'), name='profile_page')
```